# Replace href inside <!--[if mso]> tags using HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, html-agility-pack

we are using the following code to replace href values, which works great:

```
foreach (HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
{
    HtmlAttribute att = link.Attributes["href"];
    att.Value = "NewValue";
}
```

The problem comes when trying to replace the href values that are inside the Microsoft Office conditional comments like `<!--[if mso]>` (see here for further examples of this condition https://stackoverflow.design/email/base/mso/).  Currently these get ignored by HTMLAgilityPack parsing engine because it sees them as comments.

We tried temporarily replacing the conditional css with placeholders in the .text property, performing the above loop, and then swapping the placeholders out againm, but that didnt do anything so have to assume it's not reading the .text property at that stage.

Is there a "correct" way of doing this with HTMLAgilityPack?

Thanks.

Tom.

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same problem and haven't been able to find a solid solution yet that doesn't require some other text replacement logic.

You can select the comment nodes like this though:

```
htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//comment()[contains(.,'href')]")
```

But these nodes Attributes are null. So you could do some other replacement logic with the text in these nodes.